# why are binary variables appearing out of nowhere after pre-solve in gurobi?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve a fairly large MIP model in gurobi.
I am using a '.lp' file as the input to gurobi.

My problem has continuous and integer variables. But no binary variables

while solving the model on the gurobi command shell.
[image]

why are binary variables ( 93 of them) being created after pre-solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the integer variables may have bounds of `[0,1]`, before or after presolve.

Comment: so is there an advantage for the solver to treat those variables as binary ?

Comment: It can imagine how it might have some affect on cut generation, branching rules, and/or heuristics.

Comment: Thanks ! It makes sense , probably leads to  lesser branching compared to an integer variable,

Comment: As far as I know, integer variables are internally treated as binary variables anyway (with some additional constraints, of course).